# How can I set up constrained select with Jquery Ajax?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I'd like to implement automatic constrained selections of prefectures depending on the country that user chose.
It should shows only American states like California or New York or etcs, in prefecture selection field when the user chose U.S. in country field.

**Country** model has

- id
- name

**Prefecture** model has

- id
- country_id
- prefecture

Now I'm showing these field like this

```
<% resource.build_user_profile if resource.user_profile.nil? %>
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name), :html => { :method => :put, :class => 'form-horizontal' }) do |f| %>
  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

<%= f.fields_for :user_profile do |profile_form| %>

 <label class="control-label"><%= profile_form.label :country_id %></label>
 <%= profile_form_select :country, options_for_select(Countryy.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }) %>

 <label class="control-label"><%= profile_form.label :prefecture_id %></label>
 <%= profile_form_select :prefecture, options_for_select(Prefecture.all.map{ |g| [g.name, g.id] }) %>

<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you modify your HTML to write a custom select option generator you could use some JS like below.

JavaScript:

```
$(".country_select").change(function() {
  var country_id = $(this).val();
  if(country_id) {
    $(".prefecture_select option[country_id="+country_id+"]").hide();
  } else {
    $(".prefecture_select option").show();
  }
}
```

If you don't want to write a custom select helper the next easiest thing to do would be to create multiple selects and use JS to only show the one that matches the country that is selected.

Comment: Thanks. Am I supposed to make the JS file with your code?  What about controller and views? All I know is how it works if the user press the submit. But here user doesn't need to press the submit after choosing country. How do you detect whether if the user chose?

Comment: Yes you need a JavaScript file somewhere that executes this code after the DOM is ready and the form exists in the DOM. The worst, but possibly simplest, way to do this is to dup this code directly into your ERB file after the form.

Comment: If I'm putting this after the form, should I just wrap my prefecture field with <span id='country_select'>...</span>? that's it? Just copy your code and pasting will be fine???

Comment: No. I am making some assumptions about what your markup actually is. The `.country_select` should be a selector that maps to the country select. Same for the `.prefecture_select` selector.

Comment: Thanks again. I'm so sorry that I'm too noob. If possible, could you please show me an example how to set this up with controller and how the view has to be?